# Debugger attempted to resume all threads without having suspended them all before

Tags: android, lldb

I have difficulties in debugging on my Android device that is running Android 7.1.2.

I am clicking on the little green arrow and choosing the debugger next.

[image: AS green arrow]

My app is compiling, and then installing by the debugger is suddenly disconnecting.

[image: logcat]

Do you have any idea of what I need to check ?

Is there any incompatibility between lldb version between my computer and my device ? Where to find lldb version on my device ?

Thanks for your help